# Does combinatorial formula for the Pontrjagin classes exist?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Gelʹfand, I. M. and MacPherson, R. D. "A combinatorial formula for the Pontrjagin classes" Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 26 (1992), no. 2, 304–309.

In the above paper the authors claimed a construction of combinatorial formula for the Pontrjagin classes. According to mathscinet review: MR1129313, it seems the construction is not really local. So the existence of such formula is still open?

Also for first Pontrjagin class, do I understand correctly that "Gabrièlov, A. M.; Gelʹfand, I. M.; Losik, M. V. A local combinatorial formula for the first Pontrjagin class" is a well know result? If so is there any English paper gave detailed constructions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe there is a formula like the one you seek together with a good survey of the previous literature in the paper "Local formulae for combinatorial Pontrjagin classes" by Gaifullin, available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407035).

Answer (score 5):

1. That the Gabrielov, Gelfand Losik paper is "well-known" you can see from Mathscinet citation
   records.
2. This journal is translated into English.
3. Here are some other papers: MR1129313, MR0410758.